# How to make a Mean Time Before Failure graph in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, graph

Do forgive me if this is not the correct Stack Exchange site for this question (and tell me which is).

We log machine breakdowns at a production plant. Of the data logged some is Machine Downtime, Location and Date. Machine Downtime being the duration of the breakdown, Location being which set of machines and well Date, the date of the breakdown.

The graph I'm trying to make will have a column graph and a line graph. There will be a column for each breakdown and the duration dictates the height (y-axis). The line graph will start at zero and increase by one every day there isn't a breakdown. If there is a breakdown, the count will reset to zero.

The current problems encountered are: I can't get the dates on the x-axis to be spaced evenly apart by time, they are only spaced by each data point and some months have twice as many breakdowns leading to uneven spread. Another is how will I filter the Locations? I know you can filter the way I want in PivotCharts but I don't think I'll be able to use a PivotChart for this. The last is the line graph itself, what function or formula would I write to achieve this?

Comment: So basically you want to graph the Days Without Breakdown (or injury in the image) for every day? Do you HAVE to chart the data the way you specified? Because it doesn't terribly useful to just have a sawtooth of accidents. You're probably better off with just a timeline, usefulness-wise.

Comment: This makes expecting a large breakdown easier because we can see the pattern.

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: Maybe a timeline with horizontal bars for breakdowns and breakdown-free periods. it kind of depends what you're trying to express with the graphic. Sorry I'm not really answering your question. I just think it's good to think about what you're actually trying to get across, rather than cram all the data into a graph.